# Select only last inserted row per parent_id

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursorloader

Here is my `sqlite` table:

```
_ID | DATE_INSERTED | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | TRACKER_ID | DATA
```

I need to get a `Cursor` with the last inserted row (by `DATE_INSERTED`) per `TRACKER_ID`, where `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` are not equal to "`0`".

I'm doing it in a `CursorLoader`, this is where I could get:

```
public static CursorLoader getLoaderForLastMessages(Context context) {
    String sel = MessageTable.LONGITUDE + " !=? and " + MessageTable.LATITUDE + " !=?";
    String[] selArgs = {"0", "0"};
    return new CursorLoader(context, GpsProvider.MESSAGE_CONTENT_URI, null, sel, selArgs, null);
}
```

I don't know how to select only the last row per `TRACKER_ID`. I guess `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are good words, but I don't know how to use them correctly.

A raw `SQLITE` query is a good answer too, I'll adapt it to my code.

EDIT:
To clarify I need a Cursor like this:

```
_ID | DATE_INSERTED | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | TRACKER_ID | DATA
 3  | 23424123      | 13       | 43        |     1      | data
 6  | 23563344      | 25       | 56        |     2      | data
19  | 56573473      | 37       | 12        |     3      | data
43  | 23635743      | 82       | 99        |     4      | data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Table for the last inserted RowID:

//Get the last inserted unique primary id (_id) of your table.

```
public int getPrimaryId() {
    final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT MAX(_id) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE0;
    Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    int ID = cur.getInt(0);
    cur.close();
    return ID;
}
```

You can use this ID to specify in a query and load the results in your cursor.

Comment: please also tell him how not to get the value if lattitude and longitude is not equal to zero

Comment: How does it helps getting the last record PER TRACKER_ID?

Comment: He can include a WHERE clause in that if he wants that lat and long <> 0 and also other parameters!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + <TABLE_NAME> + " WHERE TRACKER_ID = \"" + <trackID> + "\" AND LATITUDE != '0' AND LONGITUDE != '0' AND DATE_INSERTED = \"" + <date>" ;
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if(cursor.moveToLast()){

//Get the value here using cursor.getString(<column number>)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a Select Query like:

```
SELECT A._ID , A.DATE_INSERTED , A.LATITUDE , A.LONGITUDE , A.TRACKER_ID , A.DATA
FROM MY_TABLE A
JOIN
(
    SELECT TRACKER_ID, MAX(DATE_INSERTED) MAX_DATE_INSERTED FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE LATITUDE <> '0' AND LONGITUDE <> '0'
) B

ON A.TRACKER_ID = B.TRACKER_ID
AND A.DATE_INSERTED = B.MAX_DATE_INSERTED
```